# How remove is auxiliary outlet navigating Angular 15

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a route `http://localhost:4200/app/articles/article/(create//left:show-article-navigate)` .

After pressing the button "Create Article" happens it: `` this.router.navigate([`/app/articles/article/page/${article.id}`]) `` .

The route looks like `http://localhost:4200/app/articles/article/(page/1200//left:show-article-navigate)` .

How do I remove `left:show-article-navigate` on button click?

I tried this:

```
this.router.navigate(\[`/app/articles/article/page/${article.id}`, { outlets: { left: null } }\]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.router.navigate([ { outlets: {primary: `articles/article/page/${article.id}`, left: null } }]);
```